# Removing the empty space between my header and equations

Tags: math-mode, vertical-spacing

this is my first question here! :)

I recently started working in Latex and I'm writing my own integration/differentiation table and I'm having an issue of empty space showing up in between and I was wondering how to remove this. Here is the picture of how it looks like (keep in mind that the red square I've created to highlight which space I'm trying to remove) and my code:

[image]

```
\setlength{\columnsep}{3cm}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{center}
    \textbf{Derivative} \\ [10pt] $\frac{d}{dx}f(x)$
\end{center}
\columnbreak
\begin{center}
    \textbf{Function} \\ [10pt] $f(x)$
\end{center}
\columnbreak
\begin{center}
    \textbf{Integral} \\ [10pt] $\int f(x) dx$
\end{center}
\end{multicols}
\noindent\rule{12.8cm}{1pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{3cm}
\begin{multicols}{3} %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{center}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    nx^{n-1}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    -\frac{1}{x^{2}}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    e^{x}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    a^{x}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    \frac{1}{x}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\end{center}
\columnbreak %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{center}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    x^{n}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    \frac{1}{x}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    e^{x}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    a^{x}ln(x)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    ln(x)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\end{center}
\columnbreak %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{center}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    ln|x|
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    e^{x}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    \frac{a^{x}}{ln(x)}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    x[ln(x)-1]
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\end{center}
\columnbreak %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{multicols}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `tabular` or variant thereof, not `multicol`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular*}{0.6\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}} % spread the columns
  *{3}{>{$\displaystyle}c<{\vphantom{\frac{1}{2}}$}} % \vphantom to equalize the row heights
  @{} % no space at the end
}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{@{}c}{\bfseries Derivative} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries Function} &
\multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{\bfseries Integral} \\
\addlinespace
\frac{d}{dx}f(x) & f(x) & \int f(x)\,dx \\
\addlinespace
\midrule
\addlinespace
nx^{n-1} & x^n & \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} \\
\addlinespace
-\frac{1}{x^2} & \frac{1}{x} & \ln\lvert x\rvert \\
\addlinespace
e^x & e^x & e^x \\
\addlinespace
a^x\ln a & a^x & \frac{a^x}{\ln a} \\
\addlinespace
\frac{1}{x} & \ln x & x(\ln x-1) \\
\addlinespace
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `tabular*` we ask TeX to spread the table to the stated width, here 70% of the whole text width.

Each cell is typeset as a math formula in `\displaystyle`, but a “phantom fraction" is added to keep the height the same for all rows.

A small, but noticeable, vertical space is added between rows via `\addlinespace`.